# Where is this textbox in the Remix IDE?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, remix

I'm using the Remix IDE. The text box this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5EipPVafsA shown at 10:35 is missing in the new version of the IDE. I'm using the same code, so where is it? Thanks!
**The textbox should be next to the deploy button in the image below.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your function (`Helius`) needs to have *exactly* the same name as the contract (`HeliusToken`) in order to be recognized as the constructor.

Then Remix will give you the option to supply arguments as seen in the tutorial.

As an aside, this tutorial uses a fairly old version of Solidity. In newer versions the constructor is defined using simply `constructor()`, which avoids this kind of confusion.